# Two dimension array, how to programically add new array element? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know, if I forgot how, or I just can't figure it out how.

For example :

```
        Object[][] data = {
            {"id", "projectname","valueid", "value"},
        };
```

And this is how they should be added, but in loop:

```
        Object[][] data = {
            {"id", "projectname","valueid", "value"},
            {"id2", "projectname2","valueid2", "value2"},
            {"id3", "projectname3","valueid3", "value3"},
        };
```

And so on..

I need a tip only, like a skeleton how it should be. I tried to figure it out, but had no idea how.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried googleing "java arrays"?

Comment: @xander yes, got some information about that, but still not enough.

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html

Comment: can you please elaborate what you exactly want know?

Comment: Whats wrong with using a hashmap for this if you need to store the keys?

Comment: Look at the answers here --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751603/how-to-insert-values-in-two-dimensional-array-programmaticaly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new array to another array like this :

```
data[1] = new Object[]{"id_1", "projectname_1","valueid_1", "value_1"};
...
data[n] = new Object[]{"id_n", "projectname_n","valueid_n", "value_n"};
```

You can use this way in any loop for example :

```
int length = 5;
Object[][] data = new Object[length][];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    data[i] = new Object[]{...some information};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        int line = i+1;
        data[i][j] = data[0][j]+ line;
    }
}
```